# Differentation uder the integral sign

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $F(x)=\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} e^{x\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy $.

My task is to calculate $F'(x)$.

My idea is to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign and I get:

$$F'(x)=\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x}\sqrt{1-y^2} e^{x\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy -\sin x \cdot e^{x\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}-\cos x \cdot e^{x\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}},$$

but now it is not any easier. The integral is still not solved. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: As you have an x in the integrand, you won't be able do get a simpler thing.

Comment: Why do you need to solve the integral? This form is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you. I just thought I should do something with the integral that remains. :-)